# Installing a Remote Event Receiver Add-in - System.IdentityModel.Tokens.SecurityTokenException

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-addin, client-object-model, remote-event-receiver

I'm working with a Remote Event Receiver Add-in in SharePoint Online and when I try to install the Add-in the breakpoint at the **HandleAppInstalled();** fires, but when it tries to use ClientContext to call the Installing method it throws an exception and the add-in can't be installed.

[image]

**The exception as follows:**

[image]

The Add-in is hosted as a Web App on Azure, and I'm using the Cloud Explorer to debug it. The RER is supposed to be installed at the "Site Pages" library and trigger when a file is *checked in*.

I've tried:

- Registrering the Add-in with new client id and secret, in the catalog and updated the values in the project.
- Updated the framework from v4.6 to v4.7
- Add-in Events Handle Add-in Uninstalled, and Installed set to True (in properties)
- The project is set to provider hosted, and the Add-in is connected to the right Web project.
- Probably more things that I can't think of now haha

[image]

***I highly appreciate any help or suggestions I can get!***

Comment: Provider hosted apps are notoriously fickle. If there's any chance you can pivot away from this approach and deploy an "app-less" RER feel free to check out my blog on the topic: https://derekgusoff.wordpress.com/2017/11/08/remote-event-receivers-youre-all-doing-it-wrong/

Comment: I'm an idiot, when calling the CheckedInEvent I used "CreateAppEventClientContext();" instead of **CreateRemoteEventReceiverClientContext();**. Now it works like I expected.
Thanks for the reply anyways!